# How to fix chromium browser cursor dragging in rtl page?

Tags: css, google-chrome

[image: draggable not under cursor 1]

[image: draggable not under cursor 2]

How to fix this bug in chromium that when the page is rtl and the element is draggable the dragged element does not show directly under cursor, but far away, like in the above image

--

simple example:

```html
<p draggable="true" dir="rtl">snippet</p>
```

---

**The problem**

the dragged item should be gripped from the right not from the left in rtl view

Comment: Could you please provide a snippet?

Comment: @Azu a simple html page with only: `<p draggable="true" dir="rtl">snippet</p>`

Comment: What browser do you use? I just tried your example and it works fine with FF and Chrome.

Comment: @Azu all the chromium based browsers have the issue, chromium + brave + vivaldi

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you use `p` which takes the whole width. Try `span`:

```html
<div dir="rtl">
        <span draggable="true">This is a snippet which takes the full width of the container. This is a snippet which takes the full width of the container. This is a snippet which takes the full width of the container. This is a snippet which takes the full width of the container. </span>
</div>
```

Comment: I do want to use the whole width

Comment: I don't get the problem. When you use `p` you could click anywhere within it and it becomes draggable. It takes the whole width so you could click anywhere on this block.

Comment: the problem is that the dragged item should be gripped from the right not from the left in rtl view

Comment: I have added more content to my sample above. It works as expected.

Comment: review the question I've added a screenshot

Comment: Very strange. My Chrome doesn't work that way. How are you able to grab the text out of it?

Comment: I am using chromium not chrome